# ArcPy Editor commits in batches of a thousand records dropping some records

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, oracle-dbms

I am copying data from one database to another using `arcpy` cursors.  This is an Oracle enterprise geodatabase against a versioned dataset.  Using Python 2.7 and ArcGIS 10.1.

The following code has worked in the past:

```
def copy_simple(target_workspace, source_fc, target_fc):
    dsc = arcpy.Describe(source_fc)
    fields = dsc.fields
    fieldnames = [field.name for field in fields if
                  field.name != dsc.OIDFieldName
                  and field.name != 'GLOBALID'
                  and field.name != 'SHAPE'
                  ]
    fieldnames = fieldnames + ["SHAPE@"]

    edit_target = arcpy.da.Editor(target_workspace)
    edit_target.startEditing(False, True)
    edit_target.startOperation()
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(source_fc, fieldnames) as sCur:
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(target_fc, fieldnames) as iCur:
            for row in sCur:
                inserted_oid = iCur.insertRow(row)
    edit_target.stopOperation()
    edit_target.stopEditing(True)
    del edit_target
```

However, while there are 17,592 records in the source feature class, there are only 17,000 records in the target at completion.  It seems that the `editor` is batching the commits in 1,000 increments and the last 592 are being dropped.

I found [this post](https://community.esri.com/thread/169204) on GeoNet, but using the `with` did not fix the problem.

This code has worked in the past without issue for different databases and feature classes.  I am not sure what environmental setting would cause this odd behavior.

**Update**:

The following code that uses an `append` approach does capture all the records:

```
def append_simple(target_workspace, source_fc, target_fc):
    edit_target = arcpy.da.Editor(target_workspace)
    edit_target.startEditing(False, True)
    edit_target.startOperation()
    arcpy.Append_management(source_fc, target_fc, 'NO_TEST')
    edit_target.stopOperation()
    edit_target.stopEditing(True)
```

This might have to be the way I go, but it would be great to try and understand what is the cause of the `cursor` not being complete.